# Selenium get last child element

Tags: python, selenium

How can I get "Hello" as an output from this code using Selenium?

```
<li class="line">
   <strong class="testing">Person</strong>
   Hello
</li>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have already tried, providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Since the text "Hello" is the last within the class `line`, you can use `[-1]` to access it.

For example, this finds an `li` with the class `line`:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.line").text.split()[-1])
```